# How to create DOM by js, using references?

Tags: javascript, dom, reference

Is it possible to generate DOM, using references?
What I have:

```
function User(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this. surname = surname;
}

var user1 = new User("John", "Smith");
```

Then I create DOM elements:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user1.name);
```

Then I want to change the name:

```
user1.name = "William"
```

If I do like this,

```
<div>John</div> wouldn't be <div>William</div>
```

The only solution I see is to create listeners which would delete old TextNode, create and append new one. 
**Question:** can I do it somehow without rewriting the textNode. May be it shouldn't be a textNode itself, but some kind of another approach.
I need a reference like behaviour.
Thank you!

Comment: I believe you're looking for a binding framework such as Knockout or AngularJS http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: That is called two-way binding (since changes in logic flows to the dom and changes in the dom flows to the logic). This tutorial might get you starteed: http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/

Comment: If I understand you correctly sounds like what you want is a data-binding.  You might want to have a look at [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) or [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) as some examples.  If you;re looking for something really light weight you could use EventEmitters and write your own updates

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will take a look on approaches in knockout, angular.. As far as I understood, they rewrite this TextNode, using innerHtml, however that's almost same. Anyway may be it's a js restriction and the only way to make data binding.